# Tkinter ball not animating?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a small tkinter app that should have a ball bouncing randomly around a canvas with the following code.

Running the code doesn't show the ball and I have no idea why. Can anyone provide some insight? I'm fairly new to tkinter and python 3

```
#GoBall
from tkinter import *
import time

Width = 800
Height = 500
Size = 50
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk,width = Width, height=Height,bg = "grey")
canvas.pack()
color = "black"
class Ball:
    def __init_(self):
        self.shape = canvas.oval(0,0,Size,Size,fill=color)
        self.speedx = 9
        self.speedy = 9
        self.active = True
        self.move_active()

    def ball_update(self):
        canvas.move(self.shape,self.speedx,self.speedy)
        pos = canvas.coords(self.shape)
        if  pos[2] >= Width or pos[0] <= 0:
            self.speedx*= -1
        if pos[3] >= Height or pos[1] <= 0:
            self.speedy *= -1

    def move_active(self):
        if self.active :
            self.ball_update()
            tk.after(40,self.move_active)

ball = Ball()
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Canvas.create_oval()` is not valid, and I'm surprised this didn't produce an error - you're invoking the method on the `Canvas` class itself, not the particular instance `canvas` that you're using.  Same issue with `Canvas.move()`.

Comment: I see, I went through the docs and changed .`create_oval` to `.oval` but and used my local object of canvas but i still have the same issue.

Comment: `.create_oval()` was correct.  `.oval()` would definitely produce an error if you ran that code - and I just noticed that the code isn't running at all because you left out one of the underscores in `.__init__()`.

Comment: @jasonharper Yup, once those two issues are fixed, the code runs fine. We caught that at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You edited your answer to introduce another error. It should be `create_oval` but the reason this isn't throwing an error is that you are missing an underscore so your init function is never running.

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
        self.shape = canvas.create_oval(0,0,Size,Size,fill=color)
        self.speedx = 9
        self.speedy = 9
        self.active = True
        self.move_active()
```

Note the double underscore ("dunder") on both sides of init.